# How to get PyCharm to display docstring in proper format?

Tags: python, text-formatting, pycharm

In PyCharm 2017.2.3, I used reStructuredText format for Python docstring.

[image: docstring for method]

And it did not display properly. Any idea how to fix it?

[image: docstring display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there should be an empty line before first `:param` to separate description. It fixed formatting for me.

Comment: Sweet, that single empty line is the key. Thanks.